# Forward ubuntu machine logs on two machines

Tags: apache, logging

I am new with ubuntu. I have three ubuntu machines A,B, C and I want to forward "A" machine logs on "B", and "C". Please someone help me thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) for this.

Also you can wrap your log output to a pipe:

```
CustomLog "|/path/to/script.pl" combined
```

And make `script.pl` to put logs to both servers via nfs.